# Rails: what's providing my API with default exception-handling?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm working on a Rails 5 JSON API, and I've noticed that it's providing sensible exception-handling out of the box.

For example, `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` results in a 404, `ActionController::ParameterMissing` results in 400, and these are all returned as well-formed JSON responses.

I've found plenty of documentation on `rescue_from`, can't locate what's providing this exception-handling for me.

I've dug around in the Rails guides, the docs, as well as in the rails console, e.g.

```
ActionController::API.new.rescue_handlers
=> []

ApplicationController.new.rescue_handlers
=> []
```

I'd like to know where the exception-handling is coming from because I've noticed that it's gracefully applied for real requests, but not in controller specs.

For example, if I run a local server and send it a malformed request with `curl`, I get a sensible error response. But if I try to reproduce that in a controller spec,

```
it "returns 404 if Yogurt doesn't exist" do
  put :update, params: { id: 293459 }
end
```

the test throws the raw exception (`ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` in this case).

Answer (score 0):

When you set up a Rails 5 app with the `--api` option you end up using `ActionController::API`. https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_controller/api.rb

The modules are built here: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/a0061d2389a178b093f0d3f64f58236ffbe088e0/actionpack/lib/action_controller/api.rb#L104 so that's where your responses are coming ultimately from. Looks like the rendering is being handed off to `metal` at some point.

API actions are configured to return `:json` by default, so that's why your test is behaving differently than your browser.

For your spec to work the same way you'll have to supply a format:
`put :update, params: { id: 293459 }, format: :json`

Comment: Adding `, format: :json` didn't change the spec behavior, unfortunately. I've looked into `metal` as well, but still no luck finding the magic.